# How to deploy a ARM template at the subscription scope using Azure Java SDK?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-java-sdk

I have an ARM template with the "subscription" scope, I can deploy it using the Azure CLI and the command: `az deployment sub create`

How do I use the Azure Java SDK to deploy this template? I have found this command that takes a resource group (or create a new one):

```
      azureResourceManager.deployments().define(deploymentName)
                .withExistingResourceGroup(rgName)  //OR .withNewResourceGroup(rgName)
                .withTemplate(templateJson)
                .withParameters("{}")
                .withMode(DeploymentMode.INCREMENTAL)
                .create();
```

But I don't find a way to deploy at the subscription level.  I know about the REST API but is there a way to do it using this Azure Java SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't find a way to deploy at the subscription level. I know
> about the REST API but is there a way to do it using this Azure Java
> SDK?

As per the [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-subscription?tabs=azure-cli),To deploy ARM templates at the subscription level it is suggested to use Azure CLI, PowerShell,REST API or the portal.

[image]

Here is the reference github [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/resources-java-deploy-using-arm-template) on how to deploy resource with Azure resource manager templates using JAVA sdk